# What is the difference between React and Preact diff algorithm in depth

Tags: reactjs, diff, preact

I've already read about differences between these frameworks in Preact's repo. I'd like to know in depth what the difference between React and Preact diff algorithms.

Both of them works with VirtualDOM.
How do Preact check that an element should be created, updated, deleted? Is `key` has the same behaviour in the frameworks? Is it use any `id` for the elements e.t.c?
Is there are any articles, discussions about the subject?

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but you might want to take a look at this [codepen](https://codesandbox.io/s/BkLpXYQn).

Comment: @HardikModha, unfortunately, I cannot open the link

Comment: Oh..That's weird. It's working fine for me. Try copy-pasting the link: https://codesandbox.io/s/BkLpXYQn

Comment: @HardikModha, thank you very much! It helps a lot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have a 30 minute talk that explains Preact's diff, including how keys work and the semantics of element creation/updates:
https://youtu.be/LY6y3HbDVmg